# Отправляю Curl xml файл, но на сервере удаляются символы

Tags: php, xml, curl

```
function checkAbonentRequest($xml){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://xxxx/index.php');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
        $result=curl_exec($ch);
        file_put_contents("logs.log", date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."Запрос серверу на проверку реквезита  ".$xml."\n",FILE_APPEND);
        return $result;
```

На сервере получаю ответ но строка обрезана

```
"1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
```

а должно быть

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

Answer (score 0):

Установите заголовок `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: text/xml']);`

Comment: когда устанавливаю заголовок curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: text/xml']); запрос вообще не доходит

Comment: странно но обрезает только до знака = , если добавляю '<=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
то в лог записывается как валидный xml но парсер выдает ошибку

Comment: проблема в том что на сервер запрос приходит как  массив  где колючем является первые символы до знака = 
ResponseT:
Array
(
    [<?xml_version] => "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <ValidateRequisiteJson xmlns="KioskSystems">
      <terminalId>5</terminalId>
      <type>Komtranscom</type>
      <requisite>1000002-5</requisite>
    </ValidateRequisiteJson>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
)

Comment: @АндрейКоваленко, в любом случае в массиве `$_POST` ваш xml должен хранится под ключом (это ассоциативный массив). Когда вы передаёте данные:`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);` переменная `$xml` должна быть либо массивом(где ключи будут соответствовать ключам в массиве `$_POST`) либо в качестве url-закодированной строки, например 'para1=val1&para2=val2'. В вашем случае передана строка, которая не является url-закодированной, но парсер этого не знает и пытается её декодировать. Отсюда и ключ '<?xml_version'

Comment: @АндрейКоваленко Добавьте данные к запросу в виде массива `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ['xml_data' => $xml]);`